# Trouble using the XLNT excel library

Tags: c++, excel, static-libraries, undefined-reference, lib

I am writing code which requires reading stuff from xls files and I settled on using the XLNT library.

I did the following:

- Configure and generate a Visual Studio project using CMAKE gui
- Compiled it in visual studio - generated a build folder with a `.lib` file
- Followed instructions on: [How to install 3rd party libraries

  codeblocks](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/)
- Added `/lib/include` directory to both linker and compiler
  search directories
- Added the `.lib` file to project build options
- Added `-std=c++14 -Ixlnt/include -lxlnt` to Other compiler options

The errors I have are:

- `undefined reference to 'xlnt::workbook::workbook()` - in total 18
  identical errors

`C:\Users\pinkunicorn\Documents\Personal Files\C\testing\main.cpp|36|undefined reference to xlnt::worksheet::freeze_panes(xlnt::cell_reference const&)'`

I looked around on forums what some people are saying re similar problems is to include the .cpp files as well.   I don't understand how to do it so I haven't tried it yet (all instructions seem to say to add .cpp library file name to the command line when compiling) - but I am not even using the command line to compile and there are like 50 cpp files in the source folder of the library download file so not sure how that would work.

what do you think possible fixes could be?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The **XLNT** didn't suport "xls" file right now,just suport "xlsx".

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use 
g++ myfile.cpp -std=c++14 -Ixlnt/include -Lxlnt/lib -lxlnt -o myfile

I believe that the order of the above is important (using the right arguments in the wrong order has tripped me up before).